# Magento 2: Finding out customer language?

Tags: magento2, customer, language

I'm making an export file of customer email addresses. Magento is set up to have two store views, each in different languages. How can I find out which store view the customer belongs to (i.e. her language)?

Answer (score 0):

The `customer_entity` table has a column `store_id`.

You can access it for example with $customer->getStoreId();

If you export the customers using your own class, you can add `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` as a dependency in the constructor. Then just loop over `$this->_storeManager->getStores(true);` and check if the store-ID matches to get the store code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/View/PersonalInfo.php:298` as an example to achieve what you want:

```
public function getCreatedInStore()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore(
        $this->getCustomer()->getStoreId()
    )->getName();
}
```